# How do I set up my Rails form to submit to a create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, form-for

I'm using Rails 5 but am confused about how to set up a form so that it submits to my "create" controller method.  Here is the route I have set up

```
  resources :comments
```

and here is the form I've set up

```
<%= form_for @comments, :html => {:class => "commentsForm"} do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <%= recaptcha_tags %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

but the above dies with teh error

```
undefined method `comments_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fdaaf2b6240>:0x00007fdaaf2ae518>
```

I'm not sure what else I should be doing to get my form to work.  In my controller I have both a "create" and a "new" method.

**Edit:** Here's the controller

```
class CommentsController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :require_current_user, except: [:new]

  def new
    @comments = Comments.new
  end

  def create
    @comments = Comments.new(params[:comments].permit(:description))
    if verify_recaptcha(model: @comments)
      render "Finished"
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: This is referring to an index path, which you do not seem to have but maybe are redirecting to?  Can you post you comments controller code in the question?

Comment: Sure I added teh controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your application comments_controller new action should be like this -

```
# app/controllers/comments_controller.rb 
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 # Rest of code here

 def new
   @comment = Comment.new # Not the @comments
 end
 # Rest of code here
end
```

And your form partial should be like this

```
# app/views/comments/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @comment, :html => {:class => "commentsForm"} do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <%= recaptcha_tags %>
 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I made the changes you specified but I still get the "undefined method `comments_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f9b3428ad80>:0x00007f9b3429af28>
" error on the same line as it complained about in my original quesiton.

Comment: Hi @Dave, I see your modified controller code. My guess your application model naming convention is wrong. The recommended model name should be Comment not Comments.

Comment: Hi @Dave, also you can regenerate your comment scaffold using this command - rails generate scaffold Comment text:string